# The Property 'Click' was not found in Type 'GroupBox'. in netcore 3.1

Tags: wpf, .net-core, click, groupbox

I have a netcore 3.1 application and would like to add a click event in order to expand / contract the content of the `GroupBox`.

Unfortunately, Visual Studio throws the error from the title which is stating that `GroupBox` does not have such an event, even though it is stated so in the [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.groupbox.click?view=net-5.0).

Code to reproduce:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="SoundStudio.Views.LibraryView.Library"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             <!-- xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SoundStudio.Views.LibraryView" -->
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Library"></Label>
        <Button x:Name="ImportButton" Content="Import" Click="ImportButton_Click"></Button>
        <GroupBox Header="Filter V" x:Name="FilterGroupBox" Click="FilterGroupBox_Click">
            <!-- <local:Filterview></local:Filterview> -->
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you have posted is for Windows Forms, the one for WPF is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.groupbox?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0). The WPF `GroupBox` does not have a `Click` event, but you can use all of the `Mouse*` events instead like:

- Defined on [`UIElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement?view=net-5.0):

  - `MouseLeftButtonDown`
  - `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`
  - `MouseLeftButtonUp`
  - `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`
  - ...
- Defined on [`Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control?view=net-5.0)

  - `MouseDoubleClick`
  - `PreviewMouseDoubleClick`

```
<GroupBox Header="Filter V" x:Name="FilterGroupBox" MouseLeftButtonDown="FilterGroupBox_Click">
   <!-- <local:Filterview></local:Filterview> -->
</GroupBox>
```

From another perspective, you might be using the wrong control in the first place.

> [...] add a click event in order to expand / contract the content of the `GroupBox`.

In this case, you could use an `Expander`, which is exactly designed for this purpose.

- [Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.expander?view=net-5.0)
- [Expander Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/expander-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Leftmouse activates when clicking on any content of the Groupbox. Is there a way of only registering the click when on border or header of the groupbox?

Comment: @julianbechtold In order to get the clicked area, you could check the parent controls in the clicked event (traverse the visual tree, e.g. using [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent?view=net-5.0)). BUT...see my updated answer. I think you are trying to re-invent the wheel as that is exactly what the `Expander` control already provides.

Comment: Thank you for the note on the Expander control. Didn't know of that one.